# In Ansible, how to access a certain element of a register variable in a loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible, ansible-2.x

I discovered the other day that when a register variable is used in a loop, like this

```
- name: Generate pw's for users
  command: "/some_path/generate_hashed_pw.sh -u {{ item }}"
  register: hashed_pws
  with_items:
  - joe
  - sally
  - john
```

the hashed_pws register is a hash that contains a results[] key, which is an array of hashes, like so

```
{
  "hashed_pws" : {
    "changed" : true,
    "some_other_key" : "some_other_value",
    "results" : [
      {
        "item" : "joe",
        "stdout": "joes_hashed_pw",
        "some_other_key" : "some_other_value"
      },
      {
        "item" : "sally",
        "stdout": "sallys_hashed_pw",
        "some_other_key" : "some_other_value"
      },
      {
        "item" : "john",
        "stdout": "johns_hashed_pw",
        "some_other_key" : "some_other_value"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So what is the syntax to directly access, the "stdout" element in each of the hash elements in the array? In other words, I want:

```
- debug: msg="Sallys hashed pw is {{ hashed_pws.results[SOME_KEY_TO_DIRECTLY_GET_SALLYS_STDOUT_VALUE] }}"
```

This is probably a python question as much as it is an Ansible question.

Comment: Also this answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39175309/2795592

Comment: Thanks @KonstantinSuvorov, the second link gave the correct idea on what I want to do.

Comment: Konstantin's link, [Loop through a registered variable with with_dict in Ansible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174539/loop-through-a-registered-variable-with-with-dict-in-ansible/39175309#39175309) provided the correct clue.

Answer (score 0):

Getting one is easy if you know which one you want:

```
print(hashed_pws['results'][1]['stdout'])
```

But if you want them all, I don't know ansible well enough to know how much looping you can do. Can you use list comprehensions?

```
print([x['stdout'] for x in hashed_pws['results']])
```

Edit based on your answer below:

```
print([x['stdout'] for x in hashed_pws['results'] if x['item'] == "sally"])
```

Comment: Your first print() is close to what I want, but I'd have to know the index value, which I don't. So I have to some how get "index with item: Sally is index 1". Yes, I can loop, but I do NOT want to loop.

Comment: I've added an example that I think does what you're asking, let me know!

Comment: thanks, but you're still looping in you edited answer.

Comment: But without knowing at which index it is, we need to examine all indexes. I don't think there's a way around that. If you look at your array of hashes, and I asked you what john's hashed passwd was, could you answer without looking at every single entry? Even a lambda function would loop. Even converting this to an indexed dictionary and accessing Sally's password would require looping over the existing list. 
I'll think about whether I've missed any options but I'm fairly sure you can';t avoid the loop.

Comment: Should really be providing an Ansible answer to this question, rather than a Python answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop over the results like this:

```
- debug: msg="{{item.item}}'s hashed pw is {{item.stdout}}"
  with_items: "{{hashed_pws.results}}"
```

Output looks like:

```
TASK [debug] 
*******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'some_other_key': 'some_other_value', 'stdout': 'joes_hashed_pw', 'item': 'joe'}) => {
    "item": {
        "item": "joe",
        "some_other_key": "some_other_value",
        "stdout": "joes_hashed_pw"
    },
    "msg": "joe's hashed pw is joes_hashed_pw"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'some_other_key': 'some_other_value', 'stdout': 'sallys_hashed_pw', 'item': 'sally'}) => {
    "item": {
        "item": "sally",
        "some_other_key": "some_other_value",
        "stdout": "sallys_hashed_pw"
    },
    "msg": "sally's hashed pw is sallys_hashed_pw"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'some_other_key': 'some_other_value', 'stdout': 'johns_hashed_pw', 'item': 'john'}) => {
    "item": {
        "item": "john",
        "some_other_key": "some_other_value",
        "stdout": "johns_hashed_pw"
    },
    "msg": "john's hashed pw is johns_hashed_pw"
}
```

Comment: Looping takes a long time. In my example I have just 3 users, but what if I have dozens? Konstantin's link in his second comment in my OP is THE answer.

Comment: Looping does not take a long time, and I'm very confused about how you solved this without a loop. The link you say helped talks specifically about looping over a dict. Are you creating a separate task for each user? That would not be good practice here and means that you would have to modify the playbook itself any time the user list changes, instead of only modifying the user list.

Comment: @ChrisF Your edit did not make any sense as part of the answer. I do appreciate that you wanted to maintain the question 2 years later, and undo a mistaken downvote, however. I've upvoted the answer on your behalf, although I think smiler171 would have appreciate a comment more so than the several reputation points he may have lost.